# Podríamos contar con una utilidad que vincule las etiquetas con los estándares de facto para clasificación de información computacional

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

En días pasados tuve que realizar algunas consultas relacionadas con los sistemas de clasificación de información existentes para un proyecto en el que estoy trabajando. Entre los sitios que visite para ello, encontré: [**ACM Computing Classification System**](https://dl.acm.org/ccs) que no conocía (ni siquiera sabía de su existencia).

Inmediatamente me pregunté si podría o no tener sentido contar con un mecanismo que pusiera en correlación las etiquetas que empleamos para clasificar nuestras preguntas/respuestas con las clasificaciones empleadas por las grandes bibliotecas digitales dedicadas a las temáticas tratadas; de modo que el "salto" desde una pregunta hasta un espacio de profundización resultara sencillo. Mi auto-respuesta: tal vez no sea de fácil implementación, pero no veo por qué no plantearlo en Meta en SOes. Así que aquí me tienen.

La pregunta: ¿Qué debemos hacer para implementar un mecanismo de correlación entre etiquetas y sistemas de clasificación, que nos brinde enlaces naturales a fuentes de documentación serias y profundas? obviamente si es viable y no afecta la naturaleza del sitio.

Comment: ¿Puedes enlazar un ejemplo de algo parecido/demo?

Comment: ¿Cuál sería el beneficio de generar esta nueva clasificación?

Comment: Gracias por la atención. **Beneficio**: si las etiquetas enlazan con estándares de clasificación, usados en bibliotecas, tanto el Op como quienes consultan, pueden saltar fácilmente a sitios que ofrecen mecanismos para profundizar y eventualmente resolver sus dudas antes de que alguien les presente una solución razonable y (si cuentan con tiempo) ofrecerla a la comunidad. **Ejemplo**:  No se de alguno en línea, tengo un desarrollo en curso que crea algo similar para equipos de investigadores en ciencia. Pero aún está crudo. Hizo parte de mi motivación a preguntar.

Answer (score 0):

La utilidad a la que te refieres ya existe y son los usuarios del sitio con privilegios de edición de etiqueta en cualquiera de sus variantes, ellos puedes agregar link externo de sugerencias o documentación a la descripción de la etiqueta.

Si te refieres a inyectarle a las páginas de la etiqueta una sección de sitios sugeridos... tendrías que definir basado en que sugieres agregar esos datos... y cuál sería el beneficio.

Hay entraría en conflicto intereses comerciales de la marca SE y SO... un script que muestre sugerencia de google/bing?

Un ejemplo seria que la etiqueta framework te sugiera usar: laravel, symfony, framework .net 4.5/5/6 etc.... basado en que lenguaje definirías las sugerencias... aquí todo se volvería caótico si no se tiene un concepto claro de que se desea hacer... y de la combinación de etiquetas en el post.

La verdad me parecería muy rebuscada la herramienta, pero no sé qué opine en general la comunidad... esta es solo mi opinión personal.

Comment: Gracias por responder. No me refiero a insertar enlaces manualmente. Se trata de mecanismos automatizados capaces de identificar correlaciones entre las etiquetas y los conceptos identificadores de "cifras" clasificadoras (como las de CDU, JEL, Biblioteca del congreso, etc) que son usadas para clasificar artículos (papers) de publicaciones indexadas y libros, con **valor académico** probado. Adicionalmente, no se trata de algo que pueda favorecer a los "*mercaderes del conocimiento*" y brindarles publicidad gratuitamente.

Comment: me estas enrredando... a ver si entiendo ... tu quieres que muestre sugerencias de libros entonces ... eso igual es un negociado...

Comment: Hola. Perdona la demora en responder (estoy viniendo poco por recarga de trabajo) los sistemas de clasificación de información hacen **fácil** encontrar documentación pertinente, vinculada con los temas en los que se necesita profundizar. Crear vínculos automáticos con ellos podría ayudar a ir más lejos que simplemente recorrer la información explícitamente vinculada en SO con cada etiqueta

Comment: si un usuario no lo recomienda en el sitio de la etiqueta y su descripcion, dudo que SO, SE implemnte alguna IA o motor para ese trabajo.

Comment: Creo que tienes razón, tal vez no se implemente en un buen tiempo. No obstante en algunos "papers" que he leido recientemente he notado la tendencia a incluir referencias a clasificaciones estandarizadas además de sus listas de palabras claves. Ojalá que esa tendencia de un impulso en la "dirección correcta".

Comment: Ojala pero aun asi no me queda claro ... si pudieras agregar un ejemplo de algo ya funcionando en algun sitio, los demas incluyendome podriamos entender con mayor exactitud lo que sugieres.

Comment: Algo similar a un ejemplo: El paper **Interpolation for Brill-Noether curves in P4**
escrito por *Eric Larson* e *Isabel Vogt* incluye en la información de referencia:
Subjects: Algebraic Geometry (math.AG) *equivale a palabras claves*
**MSC classes:** 14H99 clasificación en sistema estandarizado muy útil para documentarse en el tema.
Cite as: arXiv:1708.00028 [math.AG] 
  (or arXiv:1708.00028v2 [math.AG] for this version) referencias para hacer citación.
Enlace: 
https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1708.00028

Comment: Nota: la referencia MSC classes: 14H99 hace una generalización de la clasificación que permite navegar en sistemas de documentación afines.

Comment: el problema no es hacer ni ver el formato de la referencia ... el problema es ver un sistema automatizado que lo haga (ejemplo) ... y la url que compartista no me lleva a ningun sitio web ... XD

Comment: Justamente, no he encontrado un sistema automatizado. Yo estoy, tratando de hacer algo pero aún no tengo algo que sea mostrable. Voy a revisar el enlace y si no es correcto regreso a traer uno que funcione

Comment: El enlace al paper es: https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00028

Comment: pero la idea es que lo agregues a tu post... aun que el link que me envías funciona no se que debo de ver en el o cual es la funcionalidad no hay una explicación clara...

Comment: Justamente, de eso se trata: **no existe tal funcionalidad** en ningún sitio que haya visitado en mis búsquedas de información. **Por eso no puedo ofrecer ejemplos** y eso me motivó a plantear la inquietud aquí. De momento, he podido avanzar un poco en poner en correlación el sistema CDU de Dewey con las etiquetas que uso, con participación del usuario, en un sitio de pruebas locales pero no tengo nada que sea mostrable. Aún no logro algo significativo.

Comment: ok aun asi seria un tema de meta SE mas que de SOes ... ya que estoy casi seguro que otros sitios estarian mas interesados como el de ajedres o los de configuracion de servidores ...

Comment: Gracias por el interés demostrado.